p5js stretching image by four corners
Using the p5js javascript library, is there any way that I can take four points in 2D space and stretch the image's corners to fit those points? I can not use the texture function because it requires WEBGL which I am not using.
I know that there is an option to set the imageMode to CORNERS, but this only accepts two corners and doesn't allow the image to be stretched to anything besides a rectangle.

These are the x and y of the top left and bottom right corners, not all four

@ColeBechtel Do you mean distorting a 2D image in perspective as opposed to stretching/squashing a flat 2D image ? (If so, this answer could be handy. Potentially perspective.js could pe used with p5.js via drawingContext)

you might build this from pixels array perhaps...
